# Error handling axios request.post

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

We have an axios method like

```
export function callAcme(message) {
const requestUrl = `/api/acme/message`;
return {
    type: ACME_MESSAGE,
    promise: request.post(requestUrl, {
        data: message
    })
};
```

}

This method is mapped to an express router method, which makes a call to a third party API to get some data.

```
router.post("/acme/message", (req, res) => {
    const { data } = req.body;
    const url = "third/party/url/action;
    authenticateThirdparty({
        user: req.user
    }).then(userToken => request({
        method: "post",
        url,
        data: body,
        baseURL: url,
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`
        }
    })).then((response) => {
        res.status(200).send(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(error.status).send(error.data);
    });
});
```

The third party call is made in a `try catch` block. But id the third party method raises some error then we are are unable to send the error back to the web page who initiated the the `axios` call.

ie. In the client which invokes `callAcme` will not get the error object back.

Comment: Sorry, but your `callAcme` functions seems a redux action creator. If you are using redux you must handle this stuff with something like `redux-think`.

Comment: Yes, it is, thank you. Just started working on a reducer for this. No way to mark this as an answer, sorry

Comment: sorry... was `redux-thunk`.

Comment: Yes, I got it from the first message itself, thank you

Comment: Did you test the endpoint with Postman? What is the behavior if there is an error? Is the server hang or something?

Comment: @ Luca Fabbri  why don't you post your comment as answer?